# Refresh display settings - using xrandr / Laptop screen off, external screen on

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I set the display settings of my laptop so that when an external screen is plugged in, only the external screen is used. However, when I plug it in after being logged into Ubuntu, it stays as if no screen was plugged in. 
That is not a big problem since the display settings refresh after I go into "System Settings" > "Displays".

That is kind of unhandy, so I would like to use the terminal to refresh the display settings. I guess it has something to do with an `xrandr` command. I tried `xrandr --dryrun`, this works but outputs a lot of stuff. It doesn't seem to be the right command.

What is the correct command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the first answer did not work for me, but it brought me to to this command, which seems to do what I want:

```
xrandr --auto && xrandr --output LVDS --off
```

I will create an alias in the .bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
xrandr --auto && xrandr --output --left-of
```

or

```
xrandr --auto && xrandr --output --right-of
```

depending how your screen are arranged in **System Settings** → **Displays**.

See `man xrandr` for more info.

Comment: I tried this, too. But it turns on the external screen as well as the laptop screen. The latter one I want to be inactivated.

Comment: @aldorado Then use `xrandr --auto && xrandr --output --left-of` (or `xrandr --auto && xrandr --output --right-of`). I told you to see `man xrandr`.

Comment: This did not work for me for some reason, but combining `xrandr auto` by `&&` helped me to get to a command that works for me. Thanks a lot! I will write it down as a possible answer.